# Multiple counts from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

Need to get data from multiple tables

Currently using Count() functions, connecting to the same table more than once in some of the functions - not efficient.

Example of what's in place now - 2 sub queries both connecting to Users table

```
SELECT
(SELECT count(*) FROM Users) AS CountAll,
(SELECT count(*) FROM Table4 WHERE Table4.COLUMN3 = 0 AND Table4.userID = (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Users.status <> 0)) AS Count4,
```

what I am trying to do

```
SELECT
CountAll = count(Users.userID),
Count1 = sum(case when Table1.COLUMN1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end),
Count2 = sum(case when Table2.COLUMN2 = 0 AND COLUMN3 = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end),
Count3 = sum(case when Table3.COLUMN1 = 0 AND COLUMN2 = 'GBR' then 1 else 0 end),
Count4 = sum(case when Table4.COLUMN3 = 0 AND Users.status <> 0 then 1 else 0 end),
Count5 = sum(case when Table5.COLUMN1 = 0 AND COLUMN2 < GETDate() then 1 else 0 end)
from Users
left Join Table1 on Users.userID = Table1.userID
left OUTER Join Table2 ON Users.userID = Table2.userID 
left OUTER Join Table3 on Users.userID = Table3.userID
left OUTER Join Table4 on Users.userID = Table4.userID
left OUTER Join Table5 ON Users.userID = Table5.userID
```

Addition - didn't explain very well. I cant use correlated sub-queries as some of the tables are used more than once, eg using below Count(), Users table is used in 3 of the queries, Table1 3 times etc.

```
(SELECT Count(*) FROM Users where CONDITION1 = (SELECT COL1 FROM Table1 WHERE Users.userID = Table1.userID)) AS Count7,   
(SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 where CONDITION2 = (SELECT COL3 FROM Users WHERE Users.userID = Table1.userID)) AS Count8,
 (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table2 where CONDITION4 = (SELECT COL6 FROM Users WHERE Users.userID = Table2.userID AND Table1.COL8 = Users.COL8)) AS Count9,
```

I have to use a join for all the tables as data from each table is used in almost all of the queries, but the code returns the wrong values as soon as a JOIN is used. I've tried adding a Group clause, but that just returned multiple rows. All tables are linked by a UserID, but in most of the tables this isn't a Primary Key.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Skip the joins. Use correlated sub-queries in the select list instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I followed you correctly, one solution would be to aggregrate in subqueries *before* joining, so:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) CountAll,
    t1.cnt Count1,
    t2.cnt Count2,
    t3.cnt Count3,
    t4.cnt Count4,
    t5.cnt Count5
FROM 
    Users t
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT userID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table1 WHERE column1 = 0 GROUP BY userID
    ) t1 ON t1.userID = t.userID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table2 WHERE column2 = 0 AND column3 = 'Blue' GROUP BY userID
    ) t2 ON t2.userID = t.userID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table2 WHERE column1 = 0 AND column2 = 'GBR' GROUP BY userID
    ) t3 ON t3.userID = t.userID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table2 WHERE column3 = 0 GROUP BY userID
    ) t4 ON t4.userID = t.userID AND t.status <> 0
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT userID, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table2 WHERE column1 = 0 AND column2 < GETDate() GROUP BY userID
    ) t5 ON t5.userID = t.userID
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately most of the subqueries use the same table, so the Users table is needed in a number of results. That the problem I'm having - The sample I gave was just a small example, there's over 30 different counts needed from 6 tables.

Comment: @Sherry8212: this works fine if table `Users` is involved in a `JOIN`. See join `t4` in the answer; you just have to put the conditions on `Users` in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out it was too complicated with all the functions - bad design in the first place. After trying it with your ideas, I was able to establish that it was only 1 table that was causing the other counts to be incorrect, so I've just used a correlated sub-query where this was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have an answer here, just some questions and possible advice, none of which fits in as comments.

Those two sample queries would work quite differently from each other. The first one, I’m not sure you get any benefits from “nesting” them in a higher-level select—why not just have a series of `SELECT @MemVar = count(*) from Etc` statements?

As for the second, you are possibly processing more rows than you think. Say a given user
has one row in table one, two in table two, three in table three, and so forth.

- You start with one row, from Users
- LOJ table 1, you still have one row.
- LOJ table 2, you now have two rows for the one user
- LOJ table 3, you now have six
- Then 24
- then 120

So,

```
SELECT
   CountAll = count(Users.userID)
```

would return 120. However, add in "distinct" like so:

```
SELECT
   CountAll = count(distinct Users.userID)
```

would return 1, presuming UserID is unique (primary key, or otherwise) in table Users. Fringe benefit: any NULLs that pop up do not get counted.

The question is, which is correct for what your are counting? A lack of a primary key would be a problem here, IF you are looking to count distinct rows. If you are counting distinct values, that’s s different problem. From here, it all turns into typical “what does the data look like, what are the results your are looking for” questions.

Again, a good thing to consider is, does this need to be a single query? Can it be broken down into several smaller (faster, simpler) ones?

Comment: Thanks - it was a badly designed structure in the first place.. finally got it working by using more than one query as you've suggested.